# javascript compare positions of two coordinate pairs

Tags: javascript, cartesian-coordinates

I have a two coordinate pairs, stored as objects named `ap1 {x:x, y:y}` and `ap2 {x:x, y:y}`.
I am trying to create an if statement to see if they are exactly one of the following:

- One is one space diagonal in any direction from the other
- One is one space above or below the other

So far, the following is my code:

```
if((ap1.x == ap2.x &&(ap1.y == ap2.y + 1 && ap1.x == ap2.x || ap2.y == ap1.y + 1)) 
   || (ap1.x == ap2.x + 1 && ap1.y == ap2.y + 1) 
   || (ap2.x == ap1.x + 1 && ap2.y == ap1.y + 1)
   || (ap1.x == ap2.x - 1 && ap1.y == ap2.y - 1) 
   || (ap2.x == ap1.x - 1 && ap2.y == ap1.y - 1))
```

But with this, squares being one space to the bottom left or top right of another don't return true. How can I make this function the way I want it to?
Here is an image:
[image]

I tried another modification of my code, which does not function either:

```
if(ap1.y == ap2.y + 1||ap1.y == ap2.y - 1||(ap1.x == ap2.x + 1 && ap1.y == ap2.y + 1)||(ap1.x == ap2.x - 1 && ap1.y == ap2.y - 1))
```

Comment: This is where drawing a picture can come in handy. How does the grid work and how do your objects move? Depending on that it could be easier than you think.

Comment: Are the grid squares 1x1? Note that this is possible, it's basic collision detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at it in terms of a rectangle on top and one on bottom for the `y`. Then for the `x` position it will be either the same as `ap1`, or one to the right or the left.

```
if(((ap1.y == ap2.y + 1) || (ap1.y == ap2.y - 1)) // 1 above or bellow
    && (ap1.x == ap2.x - 1) || (ap1.x == ap2.x) || (ap1.x == ap2.x + 1)) // 3 rect points
```

Answer (score 2):

For ease of understanding you could separate the conditions like so:

```
var aboveOrBelow = ap1.y == ap2.y + 1 || ap1.y == ap2.y - 1;
var leftToRight = ap1.x >= ap2.x - 1 && ap1.x <= ap2.x + 1;

if (aboveOrBelow && leftToRight) {
}
```

Comment: Very well read code, definitely a better answer than mine. Doesn't even need an explanation `:)`